# How to load a .sigmf-meta file as JSON?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load `metadata` from a file with a `SigMF` specification as a `JSON` using `python`. Here's my code so far:

```
import json

f_path = "test.sigmf-meta"

sigmf_meta_f = open(f_path,)

sigmf_data = json.load(sigmf_meta_f)

for i in sigmf_data['sample_text']:
    print(i)

sigmf_meta_f.close()
```

This doesn't seem to work for some reason.

When I change the file extension from `"sigmf-meta"` to `"json"`, it works perfectly, but I need to be able to load these `SigMF` files without having to change all of their extensions.

Comment: [how to read sigmf-data file? #114](https://github.com/gnuradio/SigMF/issues/114)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thanks, that seemed to be what I was looking for, but could not find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you changed the extension of the file in its properties to `sigmf-meta`?

I just tried it it worked just fine, you may have not changed the extension but just the name so its `test.sigmf-meta.json` and there's no directory of `test.sigmf-meta`.

Comment: Well, that seemed to be the issue. How simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- As per [GNU Radio / SigMF: how to read sigmf-data file? #114](https://github.com/gnuradio/SigMF/issues/114)

```py
import json
import numpy as np

with open("myrecord.sigmf-meta", "r") as f:
    md = json.loads(f.read())
if md["global"]["dtype"] == "cf32_le":
    samples = np.memmap("myrecord.sigmf-data", mode="r", dtype=np.complex64)
elif md["global"]["dtype"] == "ci16_le":
    samples = np.memmap("myrecord.sigmf-data", mode="r", dtype=np.int16)
    # Convert samples to float if you want...
```